# CollectionView different cell selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios7, uicollectionview

I have a basic UICollectionView set up with 5 version of the cell. The cells populate fine. What I want to do is have each version segue to a certain view in the Storyboard (a view which I have given an ID). Is there a way to do this? I have this code which counts the number of items in the controller, however, I will always know and control how many items are in it:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return videoList.count;
```

Is there some sort of switch I can use to have the first cell go to one UIViewController, and have the second go another? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the indexPath.item as the switch. In collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:, put in if-else statements (or a switch statement) to go to different controllers based on the indexPath.item of the cell you selected.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to control this in your UICollectionViewDelegate class, specifically the collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath: method.  In here you can use the indexPath.item to determine which cell they touched, then call a [self performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] to control where in the storyboard it goes next.